# Set value to APP_BASE_HREF on click event

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

Currently I am using APP_BASE_HREF to set current language as base href of my application.

```
const appLanguageProvider: any[] = [
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
    deps: [ TranslateService ]
  }
];

export const appInitializerFactory =  (
  translateService: TranslateService,
) => {
  return translateService.currentLang;
};
```

Base href is setting up properly at app initialization stage but I want to change basehref of application when user has selected new language. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just injecting the `TranslateService` token directly in your component and setting the new language on demand?

Something like this:

```
changeLang(lang: string) {
   this.translateService.use(lang);
}
```

Comment: But I need to change language in URL too. I am setting language as base href in my application.

Comment: So are you basically looking to change provider in runtime?

Comment: Exactly this is what Ia m looking for.

Comment: I'll post an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your Token providers in runtime you can use the following trick - use the DI to inject the injector, then:

```
this.injector.create({providers: [...]})
```